# Running R commands in c++ Possible?

Tags: c++, r

I'm working on a project where it would be useful to use some the built in functionally of r, except I need it all to be in c++. What I mean by that is this:

```
  int main()
    {
       R-commands{
       test <- lm(a ~ b)
       summary(test)
      }
      some function to convert test to c++{
      some c++ code
      }
```

}

Basically I want to embed r-commands inside a c++ program on a windows machine.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: The package Rcpp might give you some pointers.

Comment: Eddelbuettel & Francois wrote [**RInside**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RInside/index.html) to do just what you're asking for. [Here's a nice intro](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) with a "Hello World" example that's just about the same length as your example.